# TYPO3 Fluid: How to get selected page categories in fluid

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fluid

I spent hours on this problem. I wanted to access the selected categories of my page in TYPO3 Fluid, but there is no default way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

There **is** no default way of doing this. You need to query the database and join tables yourself. Thanks for nothing Typo3 – nobody could have expected, that developers would actually want to access the selected categories in their templates. (╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻

In the setup Typoscript in the Fluidtemplate, add a DatabaseQueryProcessor:

```
page = PAGE
page {
    typeNum = 0
    (...)
    10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
    10 {
        (...)
        dataProcessing {
            (...)
            30 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\DatabaseQueryProcessor
            30 {
                table = sys_category
                selectFields = sys_category.*
                pidInList = root,-1
                recursive = 99
                join = sys_category_record_mm ON (sys_category_record_mm.uid_local=sys_category.uid)
                where = sys_category_record_mm.tablenames='pages' AND sys_category_record_mm.uid_foreign = ###pageuid###
                orderBy = sorting
                markers.pageuid.field = uid
                as = pageCategories
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This snippet creates a variable called `pageCategories`, which is an array of all selected categories for the current page. You can the access the title e. g. by `pageCategories.0.data.title` or loop over it in fluid:

```html
<f:for each='{pageCategories}' as='category' iteration='inter'>
    <span class='category-tag'>{category.data.title}</span>
</f:for>
```

To be honest, I don’t understand the query syntax myself, but this is a working solution. There were just a few google results for this problem, and they either didn't work in my case, of where just never answered, so I wanted to share my solution.

Credits go to [t3brightside](https://github.com/t3brightside) who maintains the [pagelist](https://github.com/t3brightside/pagelist) extension from which this code snippet was ~~inspired~~ (stolen).